# Does functional pointers not support instance types in C++

Tags: c++, oop, function-pointers

I am trying to understand how to use functional pointers to map the method from instances in C++ like delegates in C#.

```
class FunctionalPointers
{

public:

    static int IncrementCounter ( int *a, int b )
    {
        return *a += b; 
    }

    int NonStaticIncrementCounter ( int *a, int b )
    {
        return *a += b;
    }
};

//Declare a functional pointer as a separate type.
typedef int ( *AFunctionalPointer ) ( int*, int );

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 10;
    int *ptr = &a;
    *ptr = 200;

    //This works as the methods are static
    AFunctionalPointer funcInstance = FunctionalPointers::IncrementCounter;
    int result = funcInstance( ptr, a );

    //But if I try to make the same call from an
    //instance of a non static method I get an error. Why ?
    FunctionalPointers *functionalPointer = new FunctionalPointers();
    //ERROR : Compiler says it's illegal operation.
    AFunctionalPointer funcClassInstanceType = *functionalPointer->IncrementCounter;

    int instanceResult = funcClassInstanceType( ptr, a );
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see above, if a static method is assigned to the functional pointer it compiles perfectly but if I try to do the same thing with non static method with the instance of the class, the compiler throws an illegal operation error.

Mapping an instance method to a **delegate in C#** is very much possible like the snippet below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        int a = 200;
        int b = a;

        FunctionalPointer funcInstance = new FunctionalPointer();
        AFunctionalPointer degegateInstance = funcInstance.Increment;

        int result = degegateInstance( 200, 200 );
    }
}

public delegate int AFunctionalPointer( int a, int b );

class FunctionalPointer
{
    public int Increment ( int a, int b )
    {
        return a += b;
    }

    public int Decrement( int a, int b )
    {
        return a -= b;
    }
}
```

My question is,

Is it a knowledge gap on my part or is it a part of the rule in C++ to define function pointers in a different way to support instance types.

Comment: What do you mean by "functional pointer"? Is that the same as function pointer?

Comment: Yes. Similar to delegates. Sorry If I captioned it wrong. Shall I change the question heading ?

Comment: I know what delegates are, and I know what function pointers are. But when you say "functional pointer", I don't know if you mean "function pointer", or "my own class which should behave like delegates" or something else. Function pointers are not delegates

Comment: @jalf I thought functional pointers were delegates for C++ but could you enlighten me on the differences?

Comment: well, maybe the are. In C++, delegates *do not exist*, and functional pointers *do not exist*. So sure, you could say they're the same. The terms just don't mean anything to a C++ programmer. Are you by any chance thinking of *functors* or *function objects*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member pointers use different syntax. Here is your code modified to use it:

```
typedef int ( *AFunctionalPointer ) ( int*, int );
// Use this syntax to declare pointers to member functions
typedef int (FunctionalPointers::*InstFunctionalPointer) ( int*, int );

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int *ptr = &a;
    *ptr = 200;

    //This works as the methods are static
    AFunctionalPointer funcStatic = FunctionalPointers::IncrementCounter;
    int result = funcStatic( ptr, a );

    InstFunctionalPointer funcInstance = FunctionalPointers::NonStaticIncrementCounter;

    //Now when I try to make the same call from an
    //instance of a non static method I don't get an error.
    FunctionalPointers *functionalPointer = new FunctionalPointers();
    // Use this syntax to call member functions through a member pointer
    int instanceResult = (functionalPointer->*funcInstance)(ptr, a );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The idea of a delegate is to have a self-contained object, that can be used to call `(functionalPointer->*funcInstance)` *without* the caller needing `functionalPointer`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Of course, that's the idea. But prior to C++11 you needed to assemble the "closures" for your delegates from the building blocks, and pointer to member function is one of the building blocks that you need. I think that understanding pointers to members is crucial to dealing with delegates in C++ prior to C++11, so I simply fixed the OP's example to get him back on track.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Great answer! This is exactly what I wanted. A small syntax correction could be made - &FunctionalPointers::NonStaticIncrementCounter;

Answer (score 4):

C++ requires different pointer types for member functions. The C++ FAQ has a [whole section](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) on them.

You can get C#-like behavior by using the [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) wrapper from C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer to class member should be declared as:

```
int (ClassName::*FunctionPointer)(int, int);
```

Comment: Very nice article about function pointers in C++:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a function pointer as a stateful delegate; instead, you need a class that overloads the function call operator, `operator()`. This can be called like a function and also hold state, such as a particular object on which to call a member function.

In C++11, one option is `std::function`:

```
typedef std::function<int(int*,int)> delegate;
using namespace std::placeholders;

FunctionalPointers fp; // no need for "new" here
delegate d = [&](int * p, int a){fp.IncrementCounter(p,a);};

int result = d(ptr, a);
```

In C++03, you can use `boost::function` and `boost::bind` to achieve the same thing, or write your own class with an overloaded `operator()`, along the lines of:

```
class Delegate {
public:
    typedef int FunctionalPointers::*member_fn(int*,int);

    Delegate(FunctionalPointers * fp, member_fn fn) : fp(fp), fn(fn) {}
    int operator()(int * p, int a) {return (fp->*fn)(p,a);}

private:
    FunctionalPointers * fp;  // Object to call member function of
    member_fn fn;             // Member function to call
};

FunctionalPointers fp;
Delegate d(&fp, &FunctionalPointers::IncrementCounter);

int result = d(ptr, a);
```

although you'll need a bit more work still to get the polymorphic behaviour or `std::function`.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers to static member functions are essentially the same thing as pointers to functions. Pointers to non-static member functions, on the other hand, are completely different beasts, because they need an object on which to invoke that member function.

The C# expression `funcInstance.Increment` binds the object to the member function and gives you back something that can be called like a normal function. The C++ equivalent is:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std::placeholders;

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int *ptr = &a;
    *ptr = 200;

    FunctionalPointers functionalPointer;

    auto funcClassInstanceType = std::bind(
      &FunctionalPointers::NonStaticIncrementCounter, functionalPointer, _1, _2);

    int instanceResult = funcClassInstanceType( ptr, a );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-static methods are of a different type. And there's a good reason for that: they are supposed to operate on an instance of the class! You can declare a pointer to a non-static method as such

```
int (FunctionalPointers::*pointer_to_non_static_method)(int*, int)
    = FunctionalPointers::NonStaticIncrementCounter;
```

But you will need an object to use it!

Another option is to overload the `operator()` in your class:

```
class FunctionalPointers {
    ...
    int operator()(int* a, int b) { return *a += b; };
    ...
}
```

and you still need an object to use it:

```
FunctionalPointers f;
f(a,b);
```